# Binary (de-)serialization of a matrix using fwrite/fread doesn't work

Tags: c++, serialization, file-io, matrix, binary-data

I'm trying to **write/read a double matrix** to **file as binary data** but I'm not getting the correct values when reading.

I'm not sure if this is the correct procedure to do it with matrices.

---

Here's the code that I'm using to write it:

```
void writeMatrixToFileBin(double **myMatrix, int rows, int colums){
        cout << "\nWritting matrix A to file as bin..\n";

        FILE * pFile;
        pFile = fopen ( matrixOutputName.c_str() , "wb" );
        fwrite (myMatrix , sizeof(double) , colums*rows , pFile );
        fclose (pFile);
    }
```

Here's the code that I'm using to read it:

```
double** loadMatrixBin(){
    double **A; //Our matrix

    cout << "\nLoading matrix A from file as bin..\n";

    //Initialize matrix array (too big to put on stack)
    A = new double*[nRows];
    for(int i=0; i<nRows; i++){
        A[i] = new double[nColumns];
    }

    FILE * pFile;

    pFile = fopen ( matrixFile.c_str() , "rb" );
    if (pFile==NULL){
        cout << "Error opening file for read matrix (BIN)";
    }

    // copy the file into the buffer:
    fread (A,sizeof(double),nRows*nColumns,pFile);

    // terminate
    fclose (pFile);

    return A;
}
```

Comment: have you considered using `std::vector<std::vector<double> >` for your matrix and [boost::serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) for your binary serialization? Note, that it's not trivial to binary-store floating point numbers in a portable manner.

Comment: Hello, right now I'm not thinking in using the vector library or boost. But that may be a option in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `myMatrix` is not a single continuous memory area, it's an array of pointers. You have to write (and load) in a loop:

```
void writeMatrixToFileBin(double **myMatrix, int rows, int colums){
    cout << "\nWritting matrix A to file as bin..\n";

    FILE * pFile;
    pFile = fopen ( matrixOutputName.c_str() , "wb" );

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        fwrite (myMatrix[i] , sizeof(double) , colums , pFile );

    fclose (pFile);
}
```

Similar when reading.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. Seems your code works fine. But there's a little problem: `&myMatrix[i]` should be `myMatrix[i]` otherwise it will point to the pointer location instead of the _i_ row.

Comment: @RandomGuy Yeah you're right. Removed the `&` from my answer.